# Trying to automate ios application which is developed with Xcode v 8+ and automated Xcode v 9+

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am automating an ios application with appium v1.7.2 and Xcode v9.2. 
But from developer team i got to know that they developed this application with Xcode v8+.

Is it OK if go with this configuration? Is there any issue with inspecting elements?

Comment: A quick [google](https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/issues/732) suggests that there could be. What do they claim to support?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issues unless your iOS application compatible with iOS version of your test device.

E.g. `Xcode 8.3.3 includes SDKs for iOS 10.3.1`, so I'm pretty sure that tests will run normally on iOS 10.3, but you need to check with devs if your app supports **iOS 11**